# Following redirects in HTTPResponse Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I need to follow redirects given to me by HTTPost. When I make an HTTPost, and try to read the response, I get the redirect's page html. How can I fix this? Code:

```
public void parseDoc() {
    final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "https://secure.groupfusion.net/processlogin.php");
    String HTML = "";
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("referral_page",
                "/modules/gradebook/ui/gradebook.phtml?type=student_view"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currDomain",
                "beardenhs.knoxschools.org"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username
                .getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password
                .getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        String g = httppost.getURI().toString();

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String ResponseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        sting.setText(HTML);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `sting.setText`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a server sends a redirect, it is actually sending a 3xx response code (usually 301 or 302) that indicates the redirect, and a Location header that tells you the new location.

So, in your case, you can get the Location header from the [HttpResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getFirstHeader%28java.lang.String%29) object and use that to send another request to retrieve the actual content after you've logged in. For example:

```
String newUrl = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
```

So long as you reuse the same HttpClient object for both requests, it should use any cookies set by the login request in your subsequent request(s).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I looked at the source code of the redirect page, and it's using javascript on.Load method to redirect me. Will this method still  work? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm unaware of any HTTP client library that can follow JavaScript redirects. Unless you know beforehand the URL you want to request after logging in, I think your only option would be to parse out the URL from the response content.

Comment: @Eli kindly if you share the code, i am stuck in same problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) method

GetMethods will follow redirect requests from the http server by default. This behavour can be disabled by calling setFollowRedirects(false).

For more info refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getFollowRedirects%28%29)

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to log into this site using a post method, then get the source code of the home page. HTTPGet will fail the login, wouldn't it? Because it would put the login credentials in the url.

Comment: Yes your right, but then I don't know of any other way using which you can follow the redirect.

Comment: Would you suggest any other approach to my problem? I just need to log into this website and get the homepage content. Anything that can accomplish this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about the login part but if you want to get just the content refer this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166143/how-to-get-content-of-a-url-and-to-read-it-in-a-android-java-application-using-e/5166257#5166257