# Redirect to https not working from Android API rest call

Tags: android, .htaccess, http, https, url-rewrite-module

I am making my website http to https (using `letsencrypt certificate`) with redirect from http to https with following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xyz.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

I am making http API call to my website url from my android code, but it fails. When i change it to https, only then it succeeds. Why is this happening and is there a way such that http call itself from my android code can succeed.

Comment: I believe that the https url is not signed and the device is not able to trust the url.

Comment: What error do you receive? Are there relevant messages in logcat?

Comment: The Android app must follow the redirect returned by your server, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8462177/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:

- Always specify https in your android code
- For API, do NOT redirect http->https, but answer an error on the http version, it helps catch security errors faster (with a redirect they could stay undetected)